# Retrieving SQLite Pragma user_version with Golang

Tags: database, sqlite, go

This is the first project where I've used SQLite and in an attempt to do semi-automatic schema migration I would like to use the user_version pragma that has been suggested by many other answers on stackoverflow.

I am attempting to do this in Golang but am unsure if I should be using Exec, Query, or something similar to get this result and then how to render it into something usable.

within sqlite3 I can run 'PRAGMA user_version;' and it will return 3 or whatever value I have it set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `PRAGMA user_version` to read the value, this statement behaves exactly like a query, i.e., `SELECT user_version FROM somewhere`.
So just use `Query()`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the exact direction. I realized then I wasn't looping through the results of the query to scan for the value. Works great!